# Android: Attempt to invoke virtual method (onTouch) on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to set up gesture detection on one of the Linear layouts on a view in my app. The problem is my app crashes whenever I test it with a fling gesture. The error message I receive is the notorious "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference". I've done research and I understand that the problem stems from trying to call methods on an Activity that is not properly passed into the necessary scope within one's code. That being said, I don't understand how to fix that in my code. Here are the relevant bits of code:

**Playfrets.java**

```
public class PlayFrets extends Activity {
    LinearLayout gestureOverlay; 
    GestureListener gestureListener;        
    public void configGestureRecognition(){       //Toolbar gesture recognition
            gestureOverlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbarGestureOverlay);
            gestureListener = new GestureListener(PlayFrets.this);
            if (gestureOverlay == null){
                Toast.makeText(PlayFrets.this, "gestureOverlay object is null bro" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            gestureOverlay.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        }
}
```

**LoadNoteFiles.java**

```
public class LoadNoteFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
private Context mContext;
Activity instance;  

public LoadNoteFiles(Context context){ //constructor
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    PlayFrets.viewSwitch = new ViewSwitcher(mContext);
    PlayFrets.viewSwitch.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(mContext, R.layout.splash_screen, null));
    instance = (Activity)mContext;  //cast context from main activity into an activity to access setContentView method
    instance.setContentView(PlayFrets.viewSwitch);
}
...//do in background code omitted
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
    PlayFrets.viewSwitch.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(mContext, R.layout.activity_play_frets, null));
    PlayFrets.viewSwitch.showNext();
    ((PlayFrets)mContext).configFretboard();
    ((PlayFrets)mContext).configGestureRecognition(); //test gesture recognition
}
```

**GestureListener.java**

```
class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener implements OnTouchListener {
    Context mContext;
    GestureDetector gDetector;
    static final double SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = PlayFrets.getActualHeight()*(0.80);  //must swipe across at least 80% of screen height to register a gesture
    static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 150;
    static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 300;

    public GestureListener(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public GestureListener(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    public GestureListener(Context context, GestureDetector gDetector) {
        if (gDetector == null){
            gDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
        }
        this.mContext = context;
        this.gDetector = gDetector;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY) {
        //Log.e("gesture", String.valueOf(SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE));
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH|| Math.abs(velocityY) < SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                //float traveled = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
                //Toast.makeText(context, Float.toString(traveled) + ">" +String.valueOf(SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Swiped Up",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                //float traveled = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                //Toast.makeText(context, Float.toString(traveled) + ">" +String.valueOf(SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Swiped Down",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } 
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public GestureDetector getDetector() {
        return gDetector;
    }

}
```

**Do I need to use a different constructor for GestureListener.java to properly pass in an instance of the activity? What exactly is causing the onTouch() method to be called on a null object?** Below is the log detailing the error.

**log file**

```
06-15 21:59:46.721: E/InputEventReceiver(6972): Exception dispatching input event.
06-15 21:59:46.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at com.example.guitarsim.GestureListener.onTouch(GestureListener.java:59)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8914)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2673)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2385)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2346)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2346)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2346)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2346)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2346)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2552)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1767)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2840)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2513)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9125)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4636)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4474)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4024)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4077)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4043)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4157)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4051)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4024)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4077)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4043)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4051)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4024)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6485)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6384)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6355)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6575)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: How did you solve the this problem?

Comment: I passed the object I was trying to detect gestures on into the classes' constructor directly so it wouldn't be null when it was needed to receive callbacks for touches on my device screen. Check @Squonk 's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Learn to read logcat, it's telling you exactly what the problem is...

```
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference
06-15 21:59:46.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6972):   at com.example.guitarsim.GestureListener.onTouch(GestureListener.java:59)
```

The problem is at line 59 of your `GestureListener` class in the `onTouch(...)` method...

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Basically your `gDetector` must be null and there's an attempt to call its `onTouchEvent(...)` method causing the NPE.

The problem is where you create the instance of the `GestureListener` in your `Activity` method `configGestureRecognition()` as follows...

```
gestureListener = new GestureListener(PlayFrets.this);
```

The version of the constructor `GestureListener(Context context)` doesn't initialise the `GestureDetector`

Use the constructor which takes a `GestureDetector` as a parameter...

```
public GestureListener(Context context, GestureDetector gDetector) {...}
```

...and either pass in an initialised `GestureDetector` or `null` to allow it to create a `GestureDetector` for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem I have when I change the instantiation in PlayFrets.java to "gestureListener = new GestureListener(PlayFrets.this, null);" is that eclipse gives the error "The constructor GestureListener(Context, AttributeSet) is ambiguous". What would cause this ambiguous constructor error? It seems to me that the desired constructor is clearly defined in GestureListener.java

Comment: Probably that you have two constructors and each take two parameters, the first of which is `Context`. In either case you can pass null to the one with the `AttributeSet` constructor or the one with the `GestureDetector` - eclipse doesn't know which one it should be using. Why do you need one which takes `AttributeSet` anyway if you do nothing but call `super()` - if you don't need it then get rid of it. Alternatively, cast `null` to `GestureDetector` when instantiating your `GestureListener`.